# Chrome devours RAM when loading higher res GIFs?

Tags: google-chrome, memory, gif, ram

I'm currently putting together a website on bluehost, and we have an animated GIF for our home page. The GIF is around 450KB in size, with a resolution of 1500 x 600. Currently the webpage is simple with the GIF on it and a few buttons that dont really do anything. The GIF lodas nice and smoothly, but when I observe my system resources, that Chrome tab start to spike in memory usage, and goes pretty much all the way up to 750MB. (WHICH IS RIDICULOUS).

We have tried this on many different platforms and the same result occurs. We tried using other browsers, but do not come across this problem. I understand that the GIF has a large resolution, but I still find it ridiculous that it consumed that much memory space. Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Have you filed a bug-report?